# Desabilitar click no body durante um período de tempo

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

Teria algum jeito de desabilitar os eventos de click do meu `body`. Quando eu chamo uma função gostaria de desabilitar os eventos no processamento que é um pouco demorado e ao terminar ativar novamente. Já usei jQuery para adicionar o estilo `pointer-events:none;`, mas ficou com um problema ja que minha pagina e montada dinamicamente no meio desta função meus eventos de `hover` ficam bugados. Teria algum CSS tipo `clicks-events` ou algo parecido usando jQuery?

```js
function getProspect() {
   $('body').addClass('desabilitaEventos');
   $('#loadingBar').fadeIn(1000);

   //...

   $('#loadingBar').fadeOut();
   $('body').removeClass('desabilitaEventos'); 
}
```

```css
.desabilitaEventos{
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
#loadingBar{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<md-content class="md-padding backgroud-templates" style="min-height: 700px;">
  <div id="loadingBar" class="lds-css ng-scope" style="display:none;">
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%" class="lds-eclipse">
        <div></div>
    </div>    
  </div>  
<md-content/>
```

Comment: poste o que você já fez de css, html e javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível sim desabilitar todos os evento de click, basta atribuir um `stopPropagation()` no evento raiz, assim todos os outros ficam impossibilitados até o que o `listener` fora removido...

```js
ativo = false;
        function desabilitar(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              e.preventDefault();

          }
        function desabilitarClick (e) {
          if(ativo === false) {
          document.addEventListener("click",desabilitar,true);
          }
          
          ativo = true;
          
          setTimeout(function(){ document.removeEventListener("click",desabilitar,true); }, 5000);
        }
        function alertar() {
          alert('stackoverflow')
        }
```

```css
div {
          height : 200px;
          width: 200px;
          background: green;
        }
```

```html
<div onclick="alertar()">
          Click aqui
        <a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com">SOpt</a>          
        </div>
        <button onclick="desabilitarClick()">Desabilitar por 5 segundos</button>
```

Comment: Testei a resposta  colocando um elemento clicável dentro da div e outro fora da div. Os dois elementos não deixaram de ser clicáveis após acionar a função `onclick="desabilitarClick()`  do botão

Comment: Testei com vários elementos  e deu certo, afinal document é o primeiro 'path' a ser acessado pelo DOM...

Comment: Então acho que não entendi a pergunta `desabilitar os eventos de click do meu body` teste esse exemplo http://kithomepage.com/sos/teste.html

Comment: Aqui os 3 eventos pararam, após clicar no botão, porém a opção desabilitar só funciona 1 vez por conta da variável de apoio que coloquei para limitar, ou você está falando de eventos como contextmenu/scroll do mouse? são evento de click também mas basta aprimorar a função, o caminho já foi dado, enquanto a outros eventos, também podem ser adicionado preventDefault() e etc...

Comment: O link dentro da div não, se clicar vai

Comment: Ahh sim, como disse é questão de aprimoramento, basta adicionar o preventDefault, mas vou adicionar a resposta para ficar mais fácil.

Comment: Show, agora sim!!

Answer (score 3):

As demais respostas sugeriram criar uma `div` transparente sobre a página. Realmente esta é a melhor forma, porém é possível fazer de um jeito mais simples:

Crie uma `div` no `body` com um `id`:

```
<div id="tela"></div>
```

Adicione os estilos no CSS:

```
#tela {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Desabilite a `div` com `$('#tela').hide();` ou habilite com `$('#tela').show();`

Answer (score 2):

Creio que `desabilitar` o evento não seja possível, se eu estiver errado me corrija. Mas você pode fazer o seguinte:

Crie uma `div`

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Defina o *CSS*

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Posição fixada */
  width: 100%; /* Largura */
  height: 100%; /* Altura */
  top: 0; /* Define a posição topo como 0 */
  left: 0; /* Define a posição esquerda como 0 */
  display: none; /* oculta */
  z-index: 9999; /* posiciona acima de todos os elementos. */
}
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
let BTN = document.querySelector('button');
let OVERLAY = document.querySelector('#overlay');

BTN.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  console.log('Tente clicar no botão !! :) ');
  OVERLAY.style.display = 'block'; // Exibe a div
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Agora você pode clicar no botão novamente !! :D ');
    OVERLAY.style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000); // Para exemplo, apos 5 segundos oculta a div
});
```

```css
#overlay {position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; z-index: 9999; background: #000; }
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<button>BLOQUEAR</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se te atende, mas uma técnica é você fazer apenas um *overlay* com uma `<div>` por cima dos outros elementos. Mas as teclas do teclado continuarão a funcionar, pense nisso tb.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="consultar" value="Consultar" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" /><br>
<input type="text">
<div class=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Desativa os cliques em todo o "documento"**

```js
function getProspect() {

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<button type="button"/>Aguardando</button>';
    
    //Para desativar todo o clique do mouse no documento
 var event = $(document).click(function(e) {
        // Desativa todos os buttons e inputs
        $(':button,:input').prop('disabled', true);
        //Impede a propagação do evento atual.
        e.stopPropagation();
     //Cancela o evento se for cancelável, sem parar a propagação do mesmo
        e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
 });
 
 //para habilitá-los novamente após 10 segundos
 setTimeout( function() {
        // Ativa todos os buttons e inputs
         $(':button,:input').prop('disabled', false);
         $(document).unbind('click');
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="getProspect()"/>Executar função</button>';
 }, 10000 );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Executando a função do botão abaixo os clicks só voltam a funcionar depois de 10 segundos

<div id="demo"><button type="button" onclick="getProspect()"/>Executar função</button></div><br><br>

<input type="button" onclick="alert('Olá')" value="Botão alerta do ÐvÐ"/>
<br>
<div><a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered">pt.stackoverflow</a></div>

<div><a href="https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/">webmasters.stackexchange</a></div>
<br>
<a href="https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/">
<img border="0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/066AS.gif"></a>
<br>
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Botão">
<input type="button" id="myBtn2" value="Outro Botão">
<br>
<input id="" type="submit" value="Input"> <input id="" type="submit" value="Outro Input">
```

> `stopImmediatePropagation()`, previne os handlers dos elementos pais, e também previne qualquer outro handler do mesmo elemento de disparar.